# Execute a PyDev project in the Python Interactive Console?

Tags: python, console, pydev, interactive

I'm a begginer in Python and PyDev. I recently made the "helloworld" program in PyDev. My question is: how do I execute it or open it in the interactive Python mode (in Linux terminal) I tried many commands, like `./hello.py`, `import hello.py`, `python hello.py`, but the only thing I got was `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, or some other error.

I also have another question. I have Linux and I opened Eclipse in the terminal (`sudo eclipse`).

In PyDev, I first went to

```
File => New => Python Project => HelloWorld (name of project) =>
right click the project => New => PyDev Module => hello (module name).
```

It is assumed that the name I put in the terminal (running Python) is that of the module, no? Either way, I also tried with the name of the project and nothing. Just to know.

And, when do I use `chmod +x`? Every time I write it in PyDev, I get an X on the left, which means it's incorrect. Something like this: `X chmod +x`.

Comment: you shouldn't have to launch eclipse in sudo mode...

Comment: i opened normally, but now, when i write the project name tells me that the project interpreter is not specified. What should i do?

Comment: you'll have to reconfigure your workspace and pydev configuration (this is not a good habit to launch apps in sudo mode if not really needed), it won't solve your problem, but would be a better way of using eclipse ;)

Comment: You have to specify the python interpreter in the Eclipse settings, which are different depending on the user who launches it.

Comment: Can you post the code? Sounds like it has syntax errors.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python   print "hello world"    raw_input()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what you're asking now I think. If you want to execute something in a file from the shell, the easiest way is to encapsulate it in a Class.

Try changing your code to the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        print "Hello, Interactive Shell World!"
        raw_input()
```

This makes a class called Hello where the constructor function runs the code you have in your current file. Then, start an interactive shell started in the same directory as the hello.py file. Here is a paste from an example session:

```
>>> from hello import Hello
>>> Hello()
Hello, Interactive Shell World!

<hello.Hello instance at 0xb782686c>
>>>
```

It prints the message, waits for input, then prints the string representation of the newly created object and returns to the prompt. If you want to avoid the last printout just assign the object to a variable like:

```
>>> h = Hello()
```

If you want to keep the ability to execute the file from the command line (rather than the shell) add this code to the bottom of the file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Hello()
```

You do "chmod +x" from the terminal. In the directory of the hello.py, run:

chmod +x hello.py

This gives you the ability to run your file like ./hello.py instead of "python hello.py". Now that I think of it, it sounds like you may be confusing the python interactive shell which a unix shell. You can run your file easily using "python hello.py" from a unix shell, but to run code from the python interactive shell, you will want to do something like I did above.

Comment: I opened eclipse (not in sudo mode), i configured it with "auto config", then I copied that code, but when I try to execute it again i get : ImportError: No module named hello.
I tried with import hello , and: from hello import Hello
but i get the same result. any idea?

Comment: That means the file hello.py is not on the python path. The easiest way to get it on the python path is to make sure you launch the interactive python shell in the same directory as hello.py, since the current directory should always be on the python path.

Comment: how do i make sure I launched the interactive python shell in the same directory as hello.py?

Comment: in the linux terminal:

    `cd /path/to/directory/containing/hello.py/`

then `python`

Comment: it works when i write hello without .py, then, when i  start the python interactive mode writing python , then i write import hello, or from hello import Hello, or python hello.py, and i have the same problem.any idea?. And thanks for all the answers =)

Comment: before you type `python` type `ls` and press enter. That will list the contents in the current directory. If you see `hello.py` there then you should be able to enter the interactive python shell and run the code as I suggested. Otherwise, you need use `cd` to `c`hange `d`irectories to get to the directory containing `hello.py`

Comment: Please be **very** descriptive about the exact steps you take and exactly what the error is. You have been a bit skimpy on the details so far.

Comment: First of all, i configured eclipse, because before i used it in sudo mode. Then I created the "hello wolrd", the project was named hello, and the module hello.py. I wrote it in 2.7 grammar. I opened the terminal, then I wrote: cd /home/coolwater/workspace/hello , i didnt add the .py 'cause this error appear: bash: cd: /home/coolwater/workspace/hello.py/: No such file or directory (I translated the last part 'cause it was in spanish) 
when I wrote cd /home/coolwater/workspace/hello

Comment: , then the name at the left changed like this : coolwater@Cool:~/workspace/hello$ . I wrote python, python started then I wrote import hello , and for answer i get this error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named hello       
i tried with : from hello import Hello, but the result was the same , and with: python hello.py the error was this :                                 File "<stdin>", line 1
    python hello.py
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: OK, let me reiterate. "python hello.py" will work in the unix shell NOT in the python shell, but only if hello.py is in the current directory. Since you get the error "No module named hello", that tells me you are not in the correct directory. You probably created a project with source code in a "src" directory. Try `cd /home/coolwater/workspace/hello/src` before opening the python shell. Also, please do as I suggested and run `ls` before entering the python shell to verify the file is there. It would be good to get more familiar and comfortable with commands like `cd` and `ls`

Comment: IT WORKED!!! I can only thank you  recommending you to listen to this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adV8-_hgL4g        thanks men.

Comment: sorry, I need 15 reputation, as i get 15 i'll give you the point. can I make you one more question? this is the only way I can execute it, or is it there another way?

Comment: Two ways: the interactive shell way we've been discussing, or `cd /home/coolwater/workspace/hello/src` then `python hello.py`

Answer (score 0):

To configure PyDev, make sure you read its getting started manual: http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html

Now, probably you're having a syntax error because you're using Python 3, where print is no longer a keyword, but a function (so, you have to use print() as a function call), and also have in mind that raw_input() was renamed to input() on Python 3).

Comment: actually im using python 2.7. what difference does it make?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question to import into interactive mode just use `import filename` but don't include the .py

```
C:\Users\CodeThis\Documents\py\search>python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import aStar
>>> aStar.search((0,0),(5,9))
[(0, 0), (9, 0), (8, 0), (7, 0), (6, 0), (6, 9), (5, 9)]
>>>
```

something like that anyway

Comment: so i'll be importing the project name?. by the way, what is the .search?

Comment: I have a file called aStar.py in that folder, I use PyDev but my project is called something else, python just uses the filename without the `.py`. search is one of the functions i have written inside it